# Why Push Pull Can not work in this manner?

Tags: push, pull, circuit

[image: Worng Push Pull]

Why This Push Pull Type is Wrong? 
I Just Want to Switch to Positive or Negative.
Someone can explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't limits of current and / or tension.

In the PNP, and NPN transistors, The IN pin allways blow-up the transistors.

Suppose the IN pin is at 0V or GND. the PNP transistor have more than -0,7V of VBE and blows up.
Same for almost every voltage of IN pin below of VCC-0,7V = 11,3V.

The PNP transistor NOT Blows up if 11,3V<=IN<=12V=VCC. 
But when IN is in high (11,3V<=IN), the VBE of the NPN if more than 0,7V and Blows up the NPN transistor.

You need a Resistor to limit the current and tension of both Bases of transistor (R in serial with base)

Moreover.

In both circuits, when IN's voltage is VCC/2=6V. both transistors are saturated and acts as a shortcircuit (VCE almost 0V). There is not limits to the current and blow up both transistors.

**When you change from 1 to 0 or change from 0 to 1, both transistors blows up**

You need to be sure that only one transistor are active, that is saturated or closed, and not the other transistor (opened)